# Problems hosting an asp.net mvc4 application on Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2008 instance

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to host an asp.net mvc4 application on **windows 2008** server instance on **amazon ec2**, and I would like to know the complete procedure from setting up the server to connecting to the mssql database that is in the server. I am able to successfully host the application on my localhost and now would like to know the procedure to host it on amazon ec2.

I've completed the following steps:

1. Set up an **AWS account** on amazon and launched a windows 2008 sever instance.
2. Connect to the server's UI from my local machine.
3. Installed **visual studio** on the server and **IIS7**.

I even tried publishing the application and was able to access it through the URL given for the instance my application views. Now I am not able to establish database connection. The database was created through visual studio on the localhost and the same code was deployed onto the server.

I would like to know if there were any mistakes in the steps that I have followed until now and would like to know if there is any alternate procedure to host the application on the windows instance.

Any help would be great.